# Font-weight for a style doesn't work. Any idea !

Tags: css, fonts

I'm trying to set a style for a grid, and set the `font-weight` of the header to `bold` but It doesn't work

I tried to set the `font-weight` to whole the grid, but even this doesn't work !! and still appears with `normal` weight.

```
.RadGrid_MyCustomSkin
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    color:#63141A;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Could you help me with the suspected reasons?

Comment: Please show some HTML code as well.

Comment: Without some HTML and/or more CSS it is hard to tell.

Comment: And the full CSS. `font-weight` can be override.

Comment: Checking the element/s styles with Firebug or similar tool could tell you if the rule is being override or if it is not being applied (wrong class name, css format error, etc). You could first try just adding !important, as: font-weight: bold !important;.

Comment: @John what element is the grid? If it's a table, it won't work - you'll need to set each cell: `tablename td { ... }` you'll need to at least explain the HTML structure to us

Comment: @Pekka: Yes, it's table.

Comment: @Shikiryu: I removed all the font-weight from the file. I think there's no override.

Comment: @John : it could be override with a simple `font` too. Anyway, @Pekka is right in case of table and as @AJweb told you, you should check css styles override with firebug or chrome inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work in a table, giving the `table` element a font-weight won't work. You'll need to address the specific cells.

If `.RadGrid_MyCustomSkin` is the table's class, you'd need to do

```
.RadGrid_MyCustomSkin td { font-weight: bold }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was suffering with it.

Comment: But sorry, why it doesn't work with the whole table? does it need new question ?

Comment: @John it's by design in the CSS specification (there is a set of rules about how CSS properties are inherited by subsequent elements). You can start a new question but I think it has been asked before

Answer (score 0):

```
font-weight:bold !important;
```

try this maybe?